# Use a loop to delete data in a table range from multiple tables with like names

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to setup a macro to remove data from a range within a group of data tables that may change dynamically. For instance, the spreadsheet currently contains 16 data tables listed as L2_1, L2_2, L2_3.....L2_16. I'd like the macro to be flexible enough to be able to expand or contract if the number of tables changes in the sheet. I would also like to delete just the range[L2 number] within the table (this is the same range name for all of the tables).

There are also another type of tables that increment in the sheet as well ("L3L2_1, L3L2_2....L3L2_16). I'd like the macro to ignore these tables. Below is what I have started, but I receive a "1004" error at the clear contents line.

```
    Sub Summary_II_Clear_Contents()

    '   Clears Summary II Tab
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    i = 1

    For Each tbl In Sheets("Summary II").ListObjects
        If tbl.Name Like "L2_" & i Then
        Sheets("Summary II").Range("L2_&i&[L2 Number]").ClearContents
            i = i + 1
         End If
    Next tbl

    End Sub
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Change the .Clearcontents line to `Dim s1 As String`
`s1 = "L2_&i&[L2 Number]"`
`Debug.Print s1`
`Sheets("Summary II").Range(s1).ClearContents` to see what's going on. This isn't what you want, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to fix your *If statement*.
Also, you need to decide what *For Loop* construct to use.

If you decide to go with the *For Each* construct:

```
For Each tbl In Sheets("Summary II").ListObjects
    If InStr(tbl.Name, "L2_") = 1 Then
        Sheets("Summary II").Range(tbl.Name & "[L2 Number]").ClearContents
    End If
Next tbl
```

Now, you can also use the classic *For Next* construct:

```
With Sheets("Summary II")
    For i = 1 To .ListObjects.Count
        If InStr(.ListObjects(i).Name, "L2_") = 1 Then
            .Range(.ListObjects(i).Name & "[L2 Number]").ClearContents
        End If
    Next tbl
End With
```

Take note that we incorporated a *With Clause* just to make it look clean. HTH.

Comment: It looks so obvious yet I couldn't figure it out. That's great, thank you! I'll give it a whirl and see if it works!